# <urlopen error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>

Tags: beautifulsoup

All I'm trying to do is firstly get the list of link of all anchor tags and then scrape the  text of tables from each of those scraped list. But All I'm getting is an error. Can anybody please help me?

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import csv
from datetime import datetime

pages = []
my_url = 'https://deltaimmigration.com.au/Australia-jobs/'
uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

col = page_soup.find('td', width="250")
# rows = table.find_all('tr')
# print(len(col))
# print(col.text)

filename = "links.txt"
f = open(filename,'w')

headers = "Link of all jobs "
f.write(headers)

for a in col.find_all('a', href=True):
   link= a['href'] 
   f_link = link.replace(".." , "https://deltaimmigration.com.au")
   pages.append(f_link)

for items in pages:
    tables = items.find('table', width="900")
    table = tables[0]

    for table in tables:
        rows_tables = table.tbody.find_all('tr')
        rows = rows_tables[0].text
        for row in rows:
            print(row.text)

f.close()
```

Can somebody please help me to solve this? Can we not scrape the data from the scraped links from the same page? 
Error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/scrape/link.py", line 8, in <module>
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>

user@Bidhya-1s MINGW64 /e/scrape
$ C:/Users/user/Anaconda3/python.exe e:/scrape/link.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1414, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/scrape/link.py", line 8, in <module>
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your code contains much faults and completely unreadable.

I see that you are using `find` instead of `findAll` which means you are only picking the first `url`, and then I'm not even seeing any request you made to that `url` in order to `parse` it. therefor i couldn't understand your desired target as you haven't included much information. anyway from my point of view, i think that my below code will help you.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main = "https://deltaimmigration.com.au/Australia-jobs/"


def First():
    r = requests.get(main)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
    links = []
    with open("links.txt", 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        for item in soup.findAll("td", {'width': '250'}):
            item = item.contents[1].get("href")[3:]
            item = f"https://deltaimmigration.com.au/{item}"
            f.write(item+"\n")
            links.append(item)
    print(f"We Have Collected {len(links)} urls")
    return links


def Second():
    links = First()
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for link in links:
            print(f"Extracting {link}")
            r = req.get(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
            for item in soup.findAll("table", {'width': '900'}):
                print("*" * 40)
                print(item.text)
                print("*" * 40)


Second()
```

Comment: Thank you so much....but it gets stopped after scraping file from couple of links!!.....And can we save the scraped link of each site in different .txt files??

Comment: @BidhyaPokharel you are welcome, do you have any error to share ?

Comment: TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: After that I instantly got another as :<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001AE6F9D19C8>:
Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: @BidhyaPokharel seems that the website is dropping your connection due to multiple requests. you can assign a `timeout` or use `proxies` since you are scraping around 700 urls